# I'm having an issue with CachedNetworkImageProvider using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been at this for a couple of hours and I've looked at a bunch of issues that seemed to be similar to mine. I'm finding that a lot of the "fixes" are a bit outdated and aren't effective with the newer version of flutter. I'm currently on 1.17.2 and I'm using cached_network_image ^2.2.0+1.

So I am trying to display the a user profile photo with a generic placeholder if there's no photo yet or I'm pulling the save photo from Firebase, if they do have one.

Here's the snippet of code

```
_buildUserTile(User user) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 20.0,
        backgroundImage: user.profileImageUrl == null
            ? AssetImage('assets/images/user_placeholder.png')
            : CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.profileImageUrl),
      ),
      title: Text(user.name),
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => ProfileScreen(
            currentUserId: Provider.of<UserData>(context).currentUserId,
            userId: user.id,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So when I run the program, it shows the circle avatar as a blue circle and this is the error I'm getting...

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

```
  _HttpClient._openUrl  (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2282:9)
  _HttpClient.openUrl  (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2200:7)
  IOClient.send 
  package:http/src/io_client.dart:33
  HttpFileService.get 
  package:flutter_cache_manager/…/web/file_service.dart:32
  WebHelper._download 
  package:flutter_cache_manager/…/web/web_helper.dart:76

  Image provider: CachedNetworkImageProvider("", scale: 1.0) 
  Image key: CachedNetworkImageProvider("", scale: 1.0): CachedNetworkImageProvider("", scale: 1.0)
```

-Sorry for the ugly format

So it's saying No host specified in URI. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I'm not sure how to fix this. I'm very new to flutter. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! Please let me know if any more detail is needed.

Comment: print(user.profileImageUrl) and paste the link here

Comment: So I did it for one that didn't have a profile image, it was blank of course. And I did it for one that has a photo. Here it is https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/linkme-app.appspot.com/o/images%2Fusers%2FuserProfile_d5658e10-3fba-4434-a7b5-c4ac48dad181.jpg?alt=media&token=5af3443b-4841-447e-8e3c-b3c3e4cd26df

Comment: Does the on with this link load? or is it only the blank one that doesn't load?

Comment: Yes the one with the link loads. It's the blank one that doesn't. It doesn't even show a null value.

Comment: i posted an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be getting that error because your link is blank.
If you want to display the asset image when the link is blank `user.profileImageUrl.isEmpty`. code below:

```dart
_buildUserTile(User user) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 20.0,
        backgroundImage: user.profileImageUrl == null || user.profileImageUrl.isEmpty
            ? AssetImage('assets/images/user_placeholder.png')
            : CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.profileImageUrl),
      ),
      title: Text(user.name),
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => ProfileScreen(
            currentUserId: Provider.of<UserData>(context).currentUserId,
            userId: user.id,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried it and it worked. I also figured out before you posted this, that the issue occurred because it wasn't even showing as a null, it was completely blank. So I went back to the auth_service code and changed the init value to null for the profileImageUrl. I didn't even think to add an or statement for null or isEmpty!! This was so helpful thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @JideGuru JideGuru This solution not worked for me. I have network URL of `user.profileImageUrl` but image is not exist on that URL then getting exception error `CacheManager: Failed to download file from.... file URL`. Kindly share your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh It's possible that the URL doesnt work. Can you sahre the URL here?

Comment: Image file is not available on server eg. https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/edible-flowers-732x549-thumbnail321.jpg

Comment: @Kamlesh Your solution will be to add an image file to the server then

Comment: @JideGuru could you please suggest me if image is not available on server url then how can we handle it with `cachednetworkimageprovider` or `cachednetworkimage` widgets? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use `CachedNetworkImage` and not `CachedNetworkImageProvider` because `CachedNetworkImage` takes in an error callback to handle your server error. This means you won't be able to use `CircleAvatar` tho